# Validating DataGridView in C# win form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, validating

I have a DataGridView that is sourced from a datatable. I'm trying to stop the user inputting non-numerical or negative integers or doubles into different columns from the datagridview.

I understand that a CellValidating method is commonly used but I can't seem to get it to capture negative values.

```
private void datagridview1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        string headerText = datagridview1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;

        // Abort validation if cell is not in the Age column.
        if (!headerText.Equals("Quantity")) return;

        int output;

        // Confirm that the cell is an integer.
        if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out output))
        {
                MessageBox.Show("Quantity must be numeric");
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else if (output <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Quantity must not be negative");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

With the above code, I am still able to get negative or even zero values into the quantity cells.

Help is much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: This might solve the issue ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/4743070/1928632

Answer (score 1):

I think you should place `MessageBox` code after **Cancel** the event.

Because when MessageBox pops up, it loses the focus from `Cell`, losing the focus will not let the event `Cancel`.

```
// Confirm that the cell is an integer.
if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out output))
{                
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Quantity must be numeric");
}
else if (output <= 0)
{            
    e.Cancel = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Quantity must not be negative");
}
```

Comment: I've just tried it but it's not made any difference. I'm still able to put in negative values but it won't allow me to input non numeric values.
I also have a DataError event which is able to capture the user attempting to enter datatypes that are invalid and output a message, but i can't target negative values specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I think correct approach would be to make use of ErrorText property.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Quantity must not be negative";
```

This gives clear indication like:
[image]

You can also use CellEndEdit event:

```
void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // Clear the row error in case the user presses ESC.   
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = string.Empty;
        }
```

**When Row Headers are not visible:**

In that case, validation still works however error message and icon will not get displayed. Use [this approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.errortext(v=vs.110).aspx) with CellEndEdit even to get more control. This will work even when row headers are not visible.

Comment: Would this still work even if i don't have the row headers set as visible? I wanted the user interface to look cleaner. Thanks for the help!