# Catch DataGridView Cell value on editing

Tags: c#

How can I catch value Cell in `DataGridView` when user editing this cell?

I would validate on **"real-time"** input text.

Comment: you might be interested in the events that gridview offers like CellClick

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataGridView Validation & Changing Cell Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742960/datagridview-validation-changing-cell-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CellEndEdit` event for `DataGridView`.

[image: Adding CellEndEdit Event]

Then you can access cell value using following code

```
((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value
```

I just displayed data in the cell in messagebox.
Code will look like:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
    }
```